# Python is adding wrong numbers to the list

Tags: python

I am writing a Sierpinski Triangle generator, with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
from random import choice
a=np.array([[-1,0],[1,0],[0,np.sqrt(3)]])
listofpoints=[]
for i in a:
    listofpoints.append(list(i))
startpoint=[0,0.5]
listofpoints.append(startpoint)
newpoint=startpoint.copy()
for i in range(2):
    randomcorner=choice(a)
    print(i,"randomcorner",randomcorner)
    print(i,"newpoint",newpoint)
    halfdistance_x=(randomcorner[0]-newpoint[0])/2
    newpoint[0]+=halfdistance_x
    halfdistance_y=(randomcorner[1]-newpoint[1])/2
    newpoint[1]+=halfdistance_y
    print(i,"newpointadded",newpoint)
    listofpoints.append(newpoint)
print(listofpoints)
x=[]
y=[]
for i in range(len(listofpoints)):
    x.append(listofpoints[i][0])
    y.append(listofpoints[i][1])
mpl.plot(x,y,'o')
```

I encountered the issue, while I am trying to set next point, it counts them propely, however, only the last iteration value is being added this many times, as the range() says (in this example 2).

Values that I keep getting:

```
0 randomcorner [1. 0.]
0 newpoint [0, 0.5]
0 newpointadded [0.5, 0.25]
1 randomcorner [1. 0.]
1 newpoint [0.5, 0.25]
1 newpointadded [0.75, 0.125]
[[-1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.7320508075688772], [0, 0.5], [0.75, 0.125], [0.75, 0.125]]

The list in the solution should be:
[[-1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.7320508075688772], [0, 0.5], **[0.5, 0.25]**, [0.75, 0.125]]
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: if it adds only last value then it can means you have wrong indentations and you append **AFTER** loop but you should append **INSIDE** loop. Indentations can change everything. (PL: jeśli dodaje tylko ostatnią wartość to może znaczyć, że masz gdzieś złe wcięcia w kodzie i dodajesz ostatni element po wyściu z pętli a powinieneś dodawać elementy wewnątrz pętli)

Comment: or maybe all your calculations are wrong. I don't understand why you use random value. Using `choice(a)` you may get the same value few times and calculate the same results for the same value - and finally you may have only one result instead few different results.

Answer (score 0):

Code is OK.

Problem is how Python keeps `newpoint` on list. It doesn't duplicate it but it keeps references to `newpoint`. But after adding `newpoint` to list you use `newpoint` to calculate next point - so finally it modifies all points on list when you modify `newpoint`.

You have to duplicate it.

```
newpoint = newpoint.copy()
```

Or you should reassign value to variable.

```
    # use `+` instead of `-` to get directly middle point
    new_x = (randomcorner[0] + newpoint[0]) / 2
    new_y = (randomcorner[1] + newpoint[1]) / 2
    newpoint = [new_x, new_y]
```

---

Your version with `newpoint = newpoint.copy()` and `range(1000)`

And as startpoint you should use some value from list, not `[0,0.5]` because it is point in wrong place.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
from random import choice

a = np.array([[-1,0],[1,0],[0,np.sqrt(3)]])

listofpoints = []

for i in a:
    listofpoints.append(list(i))
    
startpoint = a[0]   # <--- HERE

listofpoints.append(startpoint)
newpoint = startpoint.copy()

for i in range(1000):
    randomcorner = choice(a)
    print(i,"randomcorner",randomcorner)
    print(i,"newpoint",newpoint)
    halfdistance_x=(randomcorner[0]-newpoint[0])/2
    newpoint[0] += halfdistance_x
    halfdistance_y=(randomcorner[1]-newpoint[1])/2
    newpoint[1] += halfdistance_y
    print(i, "newpointadded", newpoint)
    listofpoints.append(newpoint)
    newpoint = newpoint.copy()   # <--- HERE
    
print(listofpoints)
x=[]
y=[]
for i in range(len(listofpoints)):
    x.append(listofpoints[i][0])
    y.append(listofpoints[i][1])
mpl.plot(x,y,'o')
mpl.show()
```

Result:

[image]

---

My version with some modifications.

See also: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
from random import choice

a = [[-1, 0], [1,0], [0, 3**0.5]]
listofpoints = list(a)

newpoint = a[0]

for i in range(1000):
    print(i, "newpoint", newpoint)
    
    randomcorner = choice(a)
    print(i, "randomcorner", randomcorner)

    new_x = (randomcorner[0] + newpoint[0]) / 2
    new_y = (randomcorner[1] + newpoint[1]) / 2
    newpoint = [new_x, new_y]
    print(i, "newpoint added", newpoint)
    
    listofpoints.append(newpoint)
    print('---')
    
print('--- listofpoints ---')
print(listofpoints)

x = []
y = []

for point in listofpoints:
    x.append(point[0])
    y.append(point[1])

# OR
#for px, py in listofpoints:
#    x.append(px)
#    y.append(py)
    
mpl.plot(x, y, '.')
mpl.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I remembered about reference to start point, forgot it there, now I understand, thanks.